# excel vba - delay when writing value to a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a subroutine that retrieves a date of birth from another sheet using vlookup and writes it to the current sheet.  The sub works properly but is very slow.  I know that there are ways to speed up vba such as avoiding use of excel commands within vba code but I worked through it and found that the delay occurs when I write the date to the cell.  Any suggestions?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim finalrow As Long, DoB As Date

ActiveSheet.Unprotect

finalrow = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).row

    If finalrow > 13 Then
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(finalrow - 1, 1), Cells(finalrow - 1, 26)).Locked = True
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(finalrow - 1, 1), Cells(finalrow - 1, 3)).Interior.Color = RGB(200, 200, 200)
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(finalrow, 1), Cells(finalrow, 26)).Locked = False
        ActiveSheet.Cells(finalrow + 1, 1).Locked = False
        DoB = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ActiveSheet.Cells(finalrow, 1).Value, Sheet1.Range("A:B"), 2, False)
        ActiveSheet.Cells(finalrow, 2).Value = DoB     ' this line causes delay
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Cells(finalrow + 1, 1).Locked = False
    End If

ActiveSheet.Protect

End Sub
```

Comment: Check out `Application.Calculation` options...

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.  I'm assuming you mean setting the sheet calculation to manual at the start of the sub and back to automatic at the end.  I have tried that, along with disabling screen updates, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this is an *event procedure* which triggers on any *change* in the Worksheet, this line will actually raise the event again:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(finalrow, 2).Value = DoB
```

What you need is a way to internally disable *events* from firing *while* this event has precedence. Fortunately, there is a way to do this which is a built-in property of the Application:

You can do `Application.EnableEvents = False` (at the beginning) and then `Application.EnableEvents = True` (at the end).

This will prevent changes which occur *as a result of this procedure* from recursively raising the event.

Comment: Thank you.  Such a simple answer to an issue that has held me up all day.